# Normal Distribution - finding mean

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

I'm studying Statistical Methods and trying to revise for the upcoming exam. Looking at the past exam paper, there is a question:

```
 X ~ N (µ, 10²), and P ( X > 50) = 0.9, find µ
```

I've only before done the calculations finding z = (x - mean)/standard deviation 
and looking at the values from the Normal distribution function table. I have no idea how to approach this question. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is 100 the variance or the standard deviation?

Comment: That is all that is said in the question -  the answer is meant to be 62.816 but I have no idea how that answer was achieved.

Comment: I think it should be the sd

Comment: I took the sd to be 10.  If you work it out using the steps in my answer and do not get the right answer try sd=100.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try using the formula below. I'll let you know if I reach the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us suppose that the variance is 100.  Then the standard deviation is 10.

P$(X>50)$=P($X-mu>50-mu)$=P($(X-mu)/10 > (50-mu)/10)$=

P$(Z> (50-mu)/10)$=**0.9.**

So now you can go to the standard normal table and find what value of Z say **a** gives

P($Z>$**a**)=**0.9.**

After you find **a** you solve for mu by setting $(50-mu)/10$ = **a** and then solving for $ mu$.

Comment: As I check it you should get mu approximately equal to 62.18 when the sd=10. If you do not get that let me know what you did?

Comment: My answer was 62.816 so it did match the answer

Comment: This is a great answer. But suppose that we change the problem so that it is "X ~ N (µ, 10²), and P(–50 < X < 50) = 0.9, find µ." Am I right to think that we can't use the strategy given above, or any closer variant of it, to solve this new problem? We might start by noting that P(–50 < X < 50) = P(X < 50) – P(X < –50). But that doesn't seem to make the problem more tractable.